# deploying django-twitter-stream with apache on aws

Tags: python, django, apache, web-deployment, twitter-streaming-api

I want to use twitter streaming API.

https://github.com/michaelbrooks/django-twitter-stream

This plugin work exactly how I want and it is using tweepy library of python for same.

To run this code its expecting to run via command line i.e.

```
./manage.py stream
```

Its good to test the same in my local.

But I am not getting how to deploy the same in my aws through server where my remaining django project is already getting served via apache server

I am not pretty sure whether some sort of CRON or celery can be used in scenario.